# nav nav-tabs disable a tab using jquery not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap nav tabs as follows:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li id="tab_a" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ABC"><strong>ABC</strong></a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PQR">PQR</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#XYZ">XYZ</a></li>
   </ul>
```

I am trying to disable the **ABC** tab as follows using `jQuery` and it should not be click-able:

```
$('#tab_a a').attr('disabled', true);
```

It is not working!!

Comment: Did you consider removing the data toggle attribute? $('#tab_a a').removeAttr( "data-toggle" )

Comment: @Nakata tried not working!!

Comment: Please see my answer for a correction of the codeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in JSFiddle and it should work:

```
$('#tab_a').find('a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabled is not valid attribute for anchor. following is just work around.Kind of Inactive

Please try as follow:-

```
.disable_a_href{
    pointer-events: none;
}

$('#tab_a a').addClass("disable_a_href");
```

Added further

```
 $('#tab_a a').attr("href","javascript:void(0)")
```

Can you check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t8nrpa4e/4/)

Comment: can you check on fiddler link

Comment: Buddy your fiddle working fine. w8 let me check. In my case I have different divs for different tabs. your method only removes pointer still it is clickable!!

Comment: can you try modified answer

Comment: I mean your code only remove the mouse pointer on href. still it is clickable!!

Comment: i have added a code where altered the href which should not make it clickable

Comment: Seems to be ok. will check it and let u know!!

Comment: Alright... if it work for you then accpt the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code to make your code easier

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#tab_a').on('click', function() {
     return false;
   });
</script>
```

Then you can also put some css to change the cursor into disabled

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="tab_a" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#ABC" style="cursor: not-allowed;"><strong>ABC</strong></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PQR">PQR</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#XYZ">XYZ</a></li>
</ul>
```

hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume you're using Bootstrap 3 as I am.

I saw answers to questions like this saying that is possible to simply return `false` from `click` event to disable a tab. However, it seems this solution depends on the order that events are attached. If the Bootstrap event is triggered before your "cancellation" event, it won't work. And that was the case of the app I'm working on.

What actually worked for me was using [Bootstrap tab events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs-events).

This is how your code should look using the `show.bs.tab` event:

```
$('#tab_a a').on('show.bs.tab', function () {
    return false;
});
```

If needed, you can add extra logic inside the function.